# Adding line which scales in D3 Zoomable scatter plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I implemented this solution: http://bl.ocks.org/peterssonjonas/4a0e7cb8d23231243e0e

All is working perfectly.

I tried to add just a simple line to this chart and make it to zoom properly, I need one vertical and one 45 degrees from bottom left to top right.

I just cant find a way for zooming to work properly and I just need to add simple line here.

Comment: set up an example on jsfiddle so we can edit it.. Saying this, there are plenty of examples online

Comment: Here is the working example. BUT first you need to install Chrome extension to allow getting the .csv file with https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en.

App is on this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/L2zvz216/1/

Comment: right ok so what is it you want to do ?

Comment: I need 2 lines in there:
1. x-axis 0, y-axis: +infinity to -infinity
2. 45 degree starting from 0,0  (also -infiniti to +infinity)

Infinitiy is important because I cant see the ends of the line when zooming in-out.

Comment: Obviously you can't have infinity so youll have to adjust the line length when zooming. Could you draw what you want and add it to the question, confused on what it is you want exactly

Comment: I just want simple line (ignore all previous), that zooms properly with everything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly. You just add a line to where your dots are appended to :

```
var lineTry = objects.append('line').attr('id','lineTry')
      .attr('x1', x(0))
      .attr('y1', y(-1000))
      .attr('x2', x(0))
      .attr('y2', y(1000))
```

The above y values can be changed to the height of the graph but work for now. Then on panning or zooming :

```
  var thisTrans = d3.event.translate;
  var thisScale = d3.event.scale

  svg.selectAll("#lineTry")
    .attr('x1', x(0))
    .attr('y1', y((-1000 + thisTrans[1]) / thisScale))
    .attr('x2', x(0))
    .attr('y2', y((1000 + thisTrans[1]) / thisScale))
```

I use the previous values of 1000 etc add the current translation in the y direction then divide it by the scale :)

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/L2zvz216/2/

Comment: Crazy ;)  Thank you very very much!

Comment: How to make your jsfiddle to show Y axis only 0-200

Comment: How come you want that ? You wont be able to zoom out and you data shows values >200